# SOLR 4 master replication to SOLR 5 slave

Tags: solr, solr4, solr5

Is there any chance create master SOLR4 replication to SOLR5 slave, and after replication change slave SOLR5 to master? Or what is the best way to migrate from  SOLR 4 to SOLR 5 with convertation all indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think such feature exists (at least I'm not aware about that). A master with version X doesn't know at all the format of a later version X+Y.

Even after reading some documentation the only thing I find is this [1], but as you can read, there's nothing that helps you.

So, while I think you have to re-index your corpus (with Solr 5), in the meantime you could try to

- index data in Solr 4 (Master)
- replicate those data in Solr 5 (Slave) with a LUCENE_VERSION 4.x set in solrconfig.xml

I never tried that, but [1] says Solr 5 doesn't have retro-compatibility with 3.x, so 4.x, which is your case, should be OK. The drawback here, is that your index (on Solr 5) will be still in 4.x format.

---

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5#MajorChangesfromSolr4toSolr5-IndexFormat

Answer (score 0):

The migration from Solr4 to Solr5 is documented in the [Solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Upgrading+a+Solr+4.x+Cluster+to+Solr+5.0).